# SSHing into ec2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh

Well, there is a wierd behavior I observed recently.

On using Putty from cmd, (Windows)

> I HAVE to use "`putty -i key.ppk user@host`"

On using ssh from bash (linux)

> I HAVE to use "`ssh -i key.pem user@host`"

AWS gave me a **".pem"** file
I converted it to **.ppk** using puttygen as I understand .pem to be an older format.

**.ppk** works well with putty from windows but on using the same .ppk in linux, it asks me for a passphrase.

I tried both with and without passphrase **.ppk** files

(Below is for linux)
On creating .ppk without passphrase, it asks for one, and says permission denied no matter what i type

On creating .ppk with passphrase, it asked for one, but then even i type the correct one, it asks again and when i enter something other than the correct passphrase, the loop quits and shows permission denied.

Also, the .pem file works on linux with ssh -i , so i made it to work on both, but why this passphrase thing, can anyone please help!

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar sorry man but i am used to asking things on app and resort to others solution on desktop. Will take care from next time surely.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.ppk` file is a PuTTY only file, which is generated by PuTTYgen, where https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74545/263854 has a better and detailed introduction.

As https://askubuntu.com/questions/818929/login-ssh-with-ppk-file-on-ubuntu-terminal says, you are not expected to login SSH with `.ppk`, just only `.pem`. Though there are some tools to export a `.pem` from the given `.ppk`.